# How can I read out the disk driver series number in window system?

Tags: c++, windows, device

I've using CreateFile() to find out the device information. But some PC work, some not work? Did anyone meet this kind problem?
the code as follow:

```
sprintf(TempDriveName,"\\\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE%d",ucDriveIndex);
hDevice=CreateFile(TempDriveName,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,FILE_SHARE_READ|FILE_SHARE_WRITE,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM,NULL);
```

Comment: What does "not work" mean?

Comment: createFile() return INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE, it seem can not access this device.

Comment: And what does the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363858%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) say to do when that happens? "If the function fails, the return value is INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE. To get extended error information, call GetLastError." (Most likely this is a permission issue. Why are you opening a physical drive for writing?)

Comment: GetLastError() is 5, ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED.

Comment: Yep, so you don't have permission to open a physical disk for writing.

Comment: Please GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, the problem is why get the access denied? I've changed several parameters,but not work for some PC (windows7). there are 8 PC only 2 of them not work, all the user are administrator authority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Windows users tend to run everything as Administrator, Microsoft has locked down inherently dangerous things (like opening a physical disk for raw write) so that even administrators can't do them. You need to [request UAC elevation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control#Requesting_elevation) when you get this error when running as an administrator.

Comment: You're onto something there. The OP should compare UAC settings among the machines that work and the ones that don't.

Comment: Yes, that's the point. I found a solution for my case. Under my vs2008 project, configure the project Properties - Linker - Manifest File - UAC Execution Level (highestAvailable)
After that the program working ok. Thanks guys!